# Why same name could not be defined for namespace and enum?

Tags: c++

I know how to make the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/8vqrsGqxT) below work. But I don't ***really understand*** the reason why the compiler can't distinguish `namespace` and `enum` when they have the same name. Say, the compiler mark the `DMS` symbol as either a `namespace` or an `enum` and distinguish which one is the suitable one when analysing the context of the code snippet.

Here is the said code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace DMS {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Inside DMS namespace" << std::endl;
    }
}


enum ExampleEnum {
    DMS,
    OMS
};

int main() {
    DMS::foo();
    ExampleEnum value = DMS;
    std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be an artificial limitation, but IMO it makes sense to outright ban all name collisions, instead of figuring out what can or can't conflict with what.

Comment: By default, enumerations aren't scoped. The `DMS` enum "leaks" to where `ExampleEnum` is defined, so it conflicts with what's already defined there (same as ny declaration). You can use a scoped enumeration `enum class` to not have it "leak".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I think OP understands that, they're saying that it's always possible to disambiguate them based on the context.

Comment: *"distinguish which one is the suitable one when analysing the context of the code snippet."* This is not as easy as it sounds. Specially in a language like C++. Best is to just ban conflicting name uses altogether.

Comment: The same reason that we needed those `typename`s everywhere while most of them are no longer needed in c++20? Most of the `typename`s are no longer needed because there is strong enough motivation to make it work even though it makes the days of the compiler authors a little bit more difficult. Not that strong motivation here for this.

Comment: The problem is always the same when it comes to collisions in C++: headers. Because declarations come from outside, pasted into our TU, sometimes transitively, it's almost universally better to complain about conflicts. It'd be far worse if the meaning of a program changed silently upon a recompilation because a new collision was added (without changing source directly). That's likely why the principle HolyBlackCat mentioned is applied universally.